# Jest + Enzyme unit test a dictionary

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Pretty new to unit testing and I'm having trouble with writing a test to cover a dictionary object that I have. The tests I'm writing pass, but when I run a coverage report it says it is still uncovered.

This is what the dictionary looks like: `modals[key]` and this is what the modals object looks like

```js
const modals = {
  cartSuccessModal: 'SuccessModal',
  cartErrorModal: 'ErrorModal',
};
```

These are examples of the tests that I've tried that pass but do not properly cover the `modals[key]` line:

```js
expect(modals['cartSuccessModal']).toEqual('SuccessModal');
expect(modals['cartErrorModal']).toEqual('ErrorModal');
```

Comment: How are you declaring/importing 'modals' into the test?

Comment: Yep, that was my issue; I was just re-declaring it the same way as above in the test and not actually pulling it in from the file I'm testing. Thanks!